# Change Class-of-device (COD) of android phone through APIs

Tags: android

I would like to set/change Class-of-device of a android device through java application. Can

anyone suggest that how should I go about it ? My android device needs to make a connection

with a medical device having different class level. We do not want to touch medical device but

rather mobile phone running our app should be altered to allow Bluetooth connection be made.